# ReactiveUI notify when Property of child ViewModel changes

Tags: c#, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am quite new to ReactiveUI so I am not sure if I am missing something obvious here.

I have a ViewModel for my MainWindow which is empty and just binds to the `Content` property.

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ViewModelBase _content;

    public ViewModelBase Content
    {
        get => _content;
        private set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _content, value);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

        homeViewModel
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.CurrentItem)
            .Select(_ => new MainViewModel())
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.Content);

        Content = homeViewModel;
    }
}
```

As you can see the constructor creates a `HomeViewModel` which is the `HomeControl`'s ViewModel.
Inside this ViewModel I create a command which should just set a Property.

```cs
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ItemWrapper> _currentItem;

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, ItemWrapper> GetItemCommand { get; }

    public ItemWrapper CurrentItem => _currentItem.Value;

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        GetItemCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(getItem);

        _currentItem = GetItemCommand.ToProperty(this, x => x.CurrentItem);
    }

    private async Task<ItemWrapper> getItem() { ... }
}
```

Normally I am used to call `OnPropertyChanged` in `CurrentItem`'s setter. However, the way the documentation describes `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` this sould be called automatically. So `WhenAnyValue` should trigger inside `MainWindowViewModel` and the new ViewModel should be created.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is ViewModelBase a custom class written by you or do you use another MVVM framework in addition? Don't completely understand your code but the `.Select(_ => new MainViewModel())` looks weird to me because I don't think that your intention is to create a new main view model whenever the CurrentItem of the HomeViewModel changes.

Comment: @Đøharrrck Yeah, `ViewModelBase` is a custom class which just inherits from `ReactiveObject`. `CurrentItem` only changes one time (when the command is executed). Afterwards it doesn't change at all, because the Button which binds to the Command disappears.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize at first that MainWindowViewModel and MainViewModel were two different classes. So the content of the MainWindowViewModel is set to the instance of HomeViewModel first and is to be set to the instance of MainViewModel when the command is executed. So your question is why the HomeViewModel's CurrentItem property doesn't update when the command is executed?

Comment: @Đøharrrck Yes.

Comment: I think your code is mostly correct. Especially the implementation of the HomeViewModel is almost identical with [on of the examples in Kent Boogart's book about ReactiveUI](https://github.com/kentcb/YouIandReactiveUI/blob/master/ViewModels/Samples/Chapter%2008/Sample%2009/MainViewModel.cs). The only problem that I see is that the MainViewModel is directly created when you subscribe to the CurrentItem observable using WhenAny. This can be avoided by inserting a `Skip(1)` statement before the Select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
homeViewModel
    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.CurrentItem)
    .Select(_ => new MainViewModel())
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Content);
```

This code does nothing. You create a ObservableAsPropertyHelper object and then don't assign it to anything.  Either assign it directly:

```
_nonexistingMemberOAPH = homeViewModel.WhenAnyValue(....
```

or use a ToProperty overload that will do this for you:

```
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.Content, out _nonexistingMemberOAPH );
```